# How to make home address default?

Tags: contacts, addresses

The billing address of the user is always the default in CIVICRM. I really need the home address to be default. Is there a way to do this?

The billing address is generated from the payment processor, so paypal standard or ubercart.

Drupal 7. CIVICRM 4.5.8.

Thanks,
Andy

Answer (score 2):

You can set default Location Types From this menu:

Administer>Customize Data and Screens>Dropdown Options>Location Types

Comment: What i should of said, is how to make the home address the default primary address. When I print membership cards, it uses the primary address, but billing is set to primary even though home is the default in the settings you describe.

Comment: @ADavidson That sounds like a bug - and you're on an old version of CiviCRM, so that's entirely possible.  Could you please try replicating that on the demo site here? http://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/  If it behaves differently on the demo site, it's either a bug or a configuration issue.  For instance - do you take signups through Webform-CiviCRM, listing the billing address first?  Try moving the billing address second.

Comment: @JonG-MegaphoneTech Replicated on Civi 4.7.27 using Webform CiviCRM to take contributions. Home address is first, billing address second and provided via contribution page / payment processor. Same behaviour is described in this comment: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/135158/defining-the-primary-address-of-a-civicrm-contact#comment282034_135159

Comment: Filed issue against webform_civicrm: [Billing address always set to primary when making contribution via webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_civicrm/issues/2947955).